# Facing an issue with routing - Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I started working with Laravel last week and I'm facing a minor problem with routes.

when i do the following:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'VacatureController');
    Route::get('admin/test', array('uses' => 'VacatureController@create'));
    Route::post('admin/test', array('uses' => 'VacatureController@store'));
});
```

and i go to `admin/test`, i get an empty page.

when i change `admin/test` to something like `test/test` like:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'VacatureController');
    Route::get('test/test', array('uses' => 'VacatureController@create'));
    Route::post('test/test', array('uses' => 'VacatureController@store'));
});
```

it works fine. I looked itup in the documentation, but i didn't become anything wiser.
Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `Route::resource` as the last route. Laravel will try all routes in the order you put them in the route file, so when you put the resource route first only this one will be checked because it expects all admin routes to be there.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('admin/test', array('uses' => 'VacatureController@create'));
    Route::post('admin/test', array('uses' => 'VacatureController@store'));
    Route::resource('admin', 'VacatureController');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually fixed the issue. The explanation wasn't under `routes`, but under `controllers` in the documentation. Guess I should've digged further :)